# Не передаются данные JSON , методом AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Есть код подкорректирован но почему-то данные не передаются по AJAX, а должна записываться `1` и по повторному нажатию записывать `0`. Выводит ошибку.

ВОТ САМ ФАЙЛИК  С AJAX:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if(isset($_GET['result1']))
   {
if($_GET['result1']=="0")

echo '{"ID":"1", "result1":"0"}';

else if($_GET['result1']=="1")

echo '{"ID":"1", "result1":"1"}';
   }
?>
```

```js
    var result1 = 0;     
var button = document.getElementById('my-button');
var color = true;
button.addEventListener( "click" , function(ev){
  if (color) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#4cff00'
      result1 = 1;
} else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#6b7077'
      result1 = 0;
}
 var userId = ev.target.dataset.userId;
 var userName = ev.target.dataset.userName;
 var json = JSON.stringify({
  ID: userId,
  surname: userName
});
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET','http://localhost/tech_user/con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?result1='+result1, true);
 xhr.send();
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = result1;    
color = !color;
});
```

```css
    .cp-pen-styles >input {
      width:200px;
      height:50px;
    }
    .group-result {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 30px;
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      z-index: 0;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right:10px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en' class=''>
    <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="my-button" type="button" value="WORK" data-user-id ="1" data-user-name= "Копыча">
    <div id="result1"class="group-result">0</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, текст ошибки

Comment: GET con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?result1=1 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Правил ответ, попробуйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки, который видны на данный момент:
1. Лишняя закрывающая фигурная скобка в конце php
2. У GET запроса нет тела, поэтому send не должго иметь аргументов
3. open имеет 3 или 5 параметров

> xhr.open(method, URL, async[, user, password])

GET запрос передаётся в строке URL, например:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?result1='+result1, true);
```

Раз запрос выводит 404, значит неверно указан URL или за него считается часть

> ['result1']

Попробуйте указать его полностью и/или удалить этот аргумент.

Примерный вид php файла:

```
<?php
//Проверка на существование записи в массиве _GET
//В этот массив передаются переменные из GET запроса
if(isset($_GET['result1']){
  //Проверка значения переменной
  //P.S. Желательно обработать переменную прежде чем использовать
  //Как пример: $result1 = striptags($_GET['result1']);
  if($_GET['result1']=="0")
    //Вывод при соблюдении условия
    echo '{"ID\":"1", "result1":"0"}';
  else if($_GET['result1']=="1")
    //Вывод при не соблюдении 1го, но соблюдении 2го условия
    echo '{"ID\":"1", "result1":"1"}';
  //В ином случае ничего не будет выведено
}
?>
```

И вид запроса:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?result1='+result1, true);
```

Ошибка 404 означает, что страница по заданому URL не найдена

Comment: xhr.open('GET','con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?['result'], true);  так ?

Comment: может в пхп файле что-то не то ? (который я скинул )

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex Думал так и задумано. Во-первых php файл не даёт никакого ответа. Я сейчас напишу в ответе

Comment: Просто я только начал так сказать разбираться в этом дремучем лесу ,а тут такие лажи пошли ((

Comment: Можешь на моем примере подправить ?

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex уже

Comment: а разве без echo  ничего бы не выводилось ,не возвращало ?

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex нет. Вы просто задали значение переменной на сервере с php. На страницу это не попадает и не должно

Comment: isset я так понимаю для того чтоб проверить на наличие переменной или нет ?\

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex Сайчас поставлю коментарии

Comment: что-то не работает ,ошибка все равно ...

Comment: сейчас поправлю , но что-то одну и ту же ошибку выдает

Comment: Можешь глянуть еще разок ?

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex Я же говорю, URL поставьте полный, то есть "http://[host]/con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?result1='+result1

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Я так понял эта ошибка опять с URL связана ?

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex допишите в код, как теперь выглядит запрос. И сайт просит не вести развёрнутые обсуждения в комментариях

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80590/discussion-between-technoimpex-technoimpex-and-goodmice).